# Convert C++ log source snippet to Windows Phone C++/CX

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, c++-cli

I just started developing for Windows Phone and I'm stuck with one piece of exisiting code I need to maintain. It's a macro from a logging lib that is used in many places of existing code.

This is the macro:

```
#define LOG_FORMAT_FUNCTION(fmtarg, firstvararg) __attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, fmtarg, firstvararg)))
```

And this is a method definition that fails to use the above macro with error "{ expected" (In German "Error: Es wurde ein '{' erwartet."):

```
void LogTrace_s(const char* category, const char* format, ...) LOG_FORMAT_FUNCTION(2, 3);
```

Can you help me get rid of the error? I'd also like to know what actually the macro does exactly.

Edit: After rading this [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) I now understand that this macro is good for error checking formatted strings. Now that I know, I need it even more. But I still have no clue how to translate this to MS C++.

Comment: That's syntax that only works on another compiler, not Microsoft's.  Just omit it.  And do note that you don't use C++/CLI for Phone.  You are rather confused both about the language and compiler you use, not a good place to be.

Comment: Well I'm new as I said to WP development and all its confusing bits and pieces. What I meant was C++/CX. Yes, the above snippet compiles on GNU C++ for Andoid (via JNI). But no, I can't omit it as I said it's widely used 30k lines C++ Code). I need this to compile as part of common header to the logging - the logging itself can be wrapped and done in C#.

Comment: Isn't __attribute__ GCC-specific extension? You can think of it as of __declspec in the MSVC. Similar question was answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/483024f8-4d35-4cfc-ab01-27f37b0b0379/source-for-attribute?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 0):

Yes you CAN just omit it.  Use

```
#if _MSVC_VER
#define LOG_FORMAT_FUNCTION(fmtarg, firstvararg)
#endif
```

It is annotating the function with extra information to help gcc give you better warnings.  It does not change the behavior of the code in any way.